# Vertical multi-cursor with keyboard

Tags: atom-editor

I often need to create a vertical multi-cursor like this:

[image]

I do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking very carefully with the mouse five times below the line. Is there a shortcut for so that I can create the vertical line with the down key of my keyboard? Pressing five times the down key + ??  would be faster and more convenient for me than doing it with my mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `editor:add-selection-below`, which by default is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>.

There is of course an `-above` variant: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

And then there's `find-and-replace:select-next`<sup>1</sup>, bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, which gives you multiple cursors for similar bits of text, even when they're not vertically aligned.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> If you have the [find-and-replace package](https://atom.io/packages/find-and-replace) enabled, which you probably do since it's included with Atom by default.</sup>